# How is polymorphysm look like by using Interfaces?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, polymorphism

I don't get the connection of Interfaces To polymorphism.
Polymorphism for me is about executing a method in a different way for some different concrete classes using abstract methods or virtual methods+ overriding and therefore this is only linked to inheritance in my vision, but how do you override methods With Interfaces??
How do you use Interfaces for doing same method in different ways and giving the object to decide what to do according to its concrete type?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are Interfaces Compatible With Polymorphism](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147658/are-interfaces-compatible-with-polymorphism)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated by Andreas Hartl in [his article on Inheritance Vs. Interfaces](http://tipsandtricks.runicsoft.com/General/InheritanceVSInterfaces.html):

> Many high-level languages support inheritance and interfaces, and for
>   someone new to the concepts, it's sometimes not clear which one to
>   choose. Although languages differ in their exact handling of
>   inheritance and interfaces, the basics are usually the same, so this
>   tip should be valid for most languages.
>
> Inheritance means that we derive one class (the derived class) from
>   another class (the base class). The derived class is an extension of
>   the base class. It contains all the features (methods and data
>   members) of the base class, can extend it with new features, and can
>   reimplement virtual methods of the base class.  Some languages, like
>   C++, support multiple inheritance, where a derived class can have
>   multiple base classes, but usually inheritance is restricted to a
>   single base class.
>
> Interfaces can usually only define methods and no data members (but C#
>   for example allows data members in the form of properties within
>   interfaces), and a class can always implement multiple interfaces. An
>   interface contains only method definitions without implementations,
>   and a class that implements an interface supplies the implementation.
>
> So, using inheritance, you write a base class with method
>   implementations, and when you derive a class from it, this class will
>   inherit everything from the base class, and is immediately able to use
>   its features. An interface on the other hand is just a contract of
>   method signatures, and a class that wants to implement an interface is
>   forced to supply the implementations for all methods of the interface.
>
> So when do you use which? In some cases, the language already dictates
>   what you use: if you need your class to have multiple 'parents', you
>   cannot use inheritance in languages that don't support multiple
>   inheritance. And if you want to reuse a library object, you have to
>   use the fitting concept, depending on if that library object is a
>   class or an interface.
>
> But which to use if you are free to choose? Basically, base classes
>   describe and implement common behavior of related types, while
>   interfaces describe functionality that unrelated types can implement.
>   Inheritance describes 'is a' relationships, interfaces describe
>   'behaves like' relationships. For example, say that you are writing a
>   flight simulator. Your basic entity, which you will for example store
>   in a list, will be 'Airplane'. Your concrete types will be 'Concorde'
>   and 'Phantom'. So how should you model the three types? Concorde and
>   Phantom are related, they both are airplanes and share data, like
>   'Weight' or 'MaxSpeed' and functionality, like 'Accelerate', so we can
>   model them with inheritance. 'Airplane' will be the base class with
>   common data and methods, and 'Concorde' and 'Phantom' will derive from
>   'Airplane'. We could say that both are specialized airplanes, which is
>   why it's often said that inheritance means specialization. Now assume
>   that we also add a class 'Pilot' to our program, and we want to give
>   the user the ability to save the game and load it later. So when he
>   saves the game, we need to save the state of all Aircrafts and the
>   state of all Pilots. And we want to do this in one function that takes
>   just a list of all saveable objects. So how do we model this? To
>   answer this, we must take a look at the different types we want to
>   save. Pilots and Airplanes. It's obvious that they are not related at
>   all. They share no common data and no common functionality. We can see
>   that writing a base class 'Saveable' and derive both Pilot and
>   Airplane from it would make little sense, since no code in Saveable
>   could be reused by Airplane or Pilot, since both have no common
>   properties. In this case, an interface is the best solution. We can
>   write an interface 'ISaveable' with a method Save(). Pilot could then
>   implement ISaveable.Save() by saving his name, while Airplane could
>   save its current speed and coordinates.
>
> As you can see, a clear image of the relationship between classes
>   often makes the choice clear: Use inheritance for related types, where
>   each derived class 'is a' base class. Use interfaces for unrelated
>   types which have some common functionality.
>
> Here are some more points to consider with inheritance and interfaces:
>
> - Interfaces are fixed. When you change an interface, you have to change every class implementing that interface. But when you change a
>     base class, every derived class will gain the new functionality, which
>     can both be good (if you make a bugfix in some base class method
>     implementation, a derived class using that method will gain the bugfix
>     without you needing to change it) or bad (if a change in the baseclass
>     introduces a new bug, all derived classes using the method will be
>     bugged too).
> - Interfaces are usually more flexible, since in most languages you can only derive from one class, but implement many interfaces
> - Interfaces help to protect internal classes: Assume class A has an internal object b of class B. When a method in A returns a pointer or
>     reference to b, the code that called this method now has access to the
>     whole object b, which can be dangerous if A only wants to expose
>     certain members of b. This problem can be solved if you create an
>     interface I with just the members which are safe to expose. When B
>     implements this interface, and your method in A returns b via an I
>     pointer or reference, the outside code can only do what you allow
>     through the interface.

Comment: Dude - you typed all that in 4 minutes? ;-)

Comment: and this is where design patterns kick in. they help u make these decisions.

Comment: -1 - I thought you typed this in 4 minutes just to find out it was copy paste without giving due credit to the reference other than a vague link at the end. You shall be shamed for the day!

Comment: It's a copy of the link at the end of the text, which doesn't weaken the answer; in fact, it's nice to see something that isn't just a link only answer so that it inevitably avoids the dreaded 404 error over time. I would credit the original author clearly though - after all, they did the work.

Comment: @dash: I haven't downvoted but imho it's not _nice to see_ so much text without a comment or highlight. It's sink or swim

Comment: @TimSchmelter Agree strongly that it could be paraphrased but I've been caught out once or twice now by link only answers that go to content that no longer exists - but I didn't upvote because there's too much text without credit. Finding the right balance is important. Saying that... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147658/are-interfaces-compatible-with-polymorphism

Comment: Just placing a link at the end doesn't sufficiently indicate that the entire answer you had here was quoted from that source. I've edited the answer to provide a better citation for the original article.

Answer (score 3):

Polymorphism as a concept does not require inheritance, although in many languages inheritance is the only way to achieve it.  Some languages, like smalltalk allow you to polymorphically use any type that implements the same set of members and properties.  If it looks like a duck, quacks like a duck, and walks like a duck, you can treat it like a duck.

Polymorphism is simply the ability to treat one object as another object, by providing the same way to access and use it as the original object.  This is best illustrated by the Liskov Substitution Principle.  This is called the "Interface" or sometimes "Contract", because it defines a "signature" that another object can use to do interesting things to the object.

in C#, you can inherit from interfaces or other (non-sealed) classes.  The difference is that an interface does not provide any actual storage or methods (only their "signature"), it is merely a definition.  You can't instantiate an interface, you can only instantiate an object that implements an interface.

Classes implement an interface (IDisposable, for instance) in the same way you build a house based on blue prints.  If you build two houses with the same blueprints, then each house has the exact same "interface", they may have different color paint, or carpeting, but they function in exactly the same way, yet they are two distinctly different houses, with many differences in how various things might function.

When it comes to C#, just know that an interface says what properties or members an object that implements it *MUST* have.  Likewise, in C#, a big difference is that you can inherit multiple interfaces but only ever a single class.  (ie `public class Test : BaseClass, IDisposable, ITest, IFooBar`)

Answer (score 0):

consider this...

```
public int SomeMethod(SomeBaseClass object)
{
  // Pass in a descendant classe that implements / overrides some method in SomebaseClass
}

public int SomeMethod(ISomeInterface intf)
{
   // pass in concrete classes that implement some ISomeInterface function 
}
```

This is the basic essence of polymorphic behavior, a common contract, implemented specifically by a specialist class.

Comment: other guy wrote 2 pages and u competing with him. with a hello world?

Comment: @DarthVader - other guy copy/pasted.

Comment: 2 pages just complicates what is a pretty simple concept.